# Spring RestTemplate - Passing in object parameters in GET

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, get, resttemplate

How do I use the RestTemplate to pass in an object as a parameter?  For instance, say that I had the following services set up with Spring Boot:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> get1(@RequestParam(value = "parm") String parm) {

    String response = "You entered " + parm;
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
 }

@RequestMapping(value = "/get2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> get2(@RequestParam(value = "parm") MyObj parm) {

    String response = "You entered " + parm.getValue();
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

If a client wanted to call the first service, they could use the following:

```
//This works fine
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/get1?parm={parm}", String.class, "Test input 1");
```

But if a client wanted to call the second service, they get a 500 error using the following:

```
//This doesn't work
MyObj myObj = new MyObj("Test input 2");
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/get2?parm={parm}", String.class, myObj);
```

The MyObj class looks like this:

```
@JsonSerialize
public class MyObj {
    private String inputValue;

    public MyObj() {
    }

    public MyObj(String inputValue) {
        this.inputValue = inputValue;
    }

    public String getInputValue() {
        return inputValue;
    }

    public void setInputValue(String inputValue) {
        this.inputValue = inputValue;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that the problem is that the myObj is not getting properly setup as a parameter.  How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using a complex object (like `MyObj`) as a `@RequestParam`, Spring will try to convert a string to that complex object. In this case, because `MyObj` has only a single `String` field called `inputValue` it will automagically use whatever value you provide to your query parmeter to fill the property in your object.

For example, if you call: `http://localhost:8080/get2?parm=foobar` you'll get a `MyObj` where `inputValue` will be `"foobar"`.

If you use `RestTemplate` you shouldn't get an error, but in stead it will try to convert `new MyObj("Test input 2")` to a string, using the `toString()` method and the response will be:

> You entered com.example.MyObj@63a815e8

---

This is probably not what you want. Generally you don't want to pass complex objects as request parameters, you can use `@RequestBody` with `RequestMethod.POST` and `restTemplate.postForEntity()` to properly pass your `MyObj` as JSON.

Change your controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> get2(@RequestBody MyObj parm) {

    String response = "You entered " + parm.getInputValue();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And call it using `RestTemplate` like this:

```
MyObj myObj = new MyObj("Test input 2");
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/get2", myObj, String.class).getBody();
```

This will properly pass your object as JSON.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer! Actually, lots of popele (if not everyone :) ) always marshal/unmarschal objects as JSON. I'm always wondering why not implementing an interface in both client and server side? As long as you don't open your service to the world, I believe it perfectly make it ...

Comment: @hublo That's what I often do at projects, the REST client on the consumer side could implement the same interface as the REST service on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass value of each URI parameter after `responseType`.  Problem is that `RestTemplate` does not know how to map your object to URI parameters. You have to explicitly call appropriate `myObj` method to retrieve the actual value:

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(
    "http://localhost:8080/get2?parm={parm}", String.class,
    myObj.getInputValue());
```

Signature of the `getForObject` method you call is:
`public <T> T getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... urlVariables) throws  ….`

where `urlVariables` is array of URI variable **values** to expand the URI with.

Answer (score -2):

i'm guessing 
this:

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/get2?parm={parm}", String.class, myObj)
```

should change as

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/get2?parm={parm}", MyObj.class, myObj)
```

Comment: No, the second parameter (`String.class`) is used to describe the **return type** of the response. The response in both `/get1` and `/get2` is a `String` it's the request parameter that changes.